# Is the "Simulate clicking by hovering" Ubuntu feature present in some form in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, accessibility

Ubuntu has a nice [simulate clicking by hovering](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-dwellclick.html) feature. Does Kubuntu 15.10 have a similar feature?

> When Hover Click is enabled, you can move your mouse pointer over a control, let go of the mouse, and then wait for a while before the button will be clicked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In KDE, you can use **KMouseTool**.   If it is not already installed, you  may install it:

```
sudo apt-get install kmousetool
```

From [KDE documentation site](https://docs.kde.org/):

> Using KMouseTool is simple: KMouseTool watches as you move the mouse, and when you pause briefly, it clicks.
>
> KMouseTool's Smart Drag mode allows you to drag the mouse.
>
> When Smart Drag is enabled, KMouseTool pauses after it clicks down; if you move the mouse, it waits until you stop moving before it clicks up. This way, you can both click and drag the mouse. Smart Drag takes a bit more practice, but becomes natural once you get used to it.

[image]